# Assignment as method argument, how to do that in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I am converting an application to VB.Net and I can't figure out how to convert the line below into VB.Net. This application has reference to Sharepoint so the object is referring to sharepoint component.

```
context.Load(item = listFields.GetItemById(listItemId);
```

Any suggestions how to convert this to vb.net ?

Comment: `item = listFields.GetItemById(listItemId)  context.Load( item )`

Comment: To VB.Net:

`context.Load(InlineAssignHelper(item, listFields.GetItemById(listItemId)))`


you can use this site for future conversions: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb

Comment: @TimSchmelter put your suggestion in the answer section and I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: @PSantos, InlineAssignHelper is something that's generated by code converters, but doesn't actually work if you copy/paste it into code.

Comment: @PSantos.. interesting site. Thanks for the information

Comment: @user2366842

you can define this function like this:

`Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, value As T) As T
   target = value
   Return value
End Function`

it assigns 'value' to the variable passed in by reference and also returns 'value'.

Comment: Fair enough, if that block of code is included, it should work, a straight copy/paste of code from a code generator won't work without it being defined though.  Might be a handy chunk of code to have around though, as I stumble across that once in a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't like this C# way to assign a variable and directly use it. I would also write it on two lines in C#:

```
item = listFields.GetItemById(listItemId);
context.Load(item);
```

Is it now clear?

There's one exception when i find it useful to consume the return value of an asssignment expression directly which is not supported in VB.NET:

```
string line;
using(var reader = new StreamReader("Path"))
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

In VB.NET you'd need ugly code like this:

```
Using reader = New StreamReader("Path")
    Do
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        If line Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        ' ... '
    Loop
End Using
```

That's why i prefer the `File` class in most cases, so for example:

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("Path")
    ' ... '
Next
```

Comment: Yes and I agree and good to know that I am not the only one who would use two lines rather than jam everything into one line. Thanks very much. Will accept your answer in 7 minutes :)

Comment: Personally, I almost always try to break it apart into two lines, because as you pointed out, it can sometimes get a little rough from a readability aspect.